# CMake finding directory of proper name

Tags: directory, cmake, find

So as in the question.

I have structure of folders lets say like this:

```
|-root
|  |
|  |-someFolder
|  |  |
|  |  |-someSubFolder
|  |
|  |-someAnotherFolder
```

etc. in general I don't know far folder can be nested, but I need sometimes to
find path to a folder, that I don't know it's location (only name).

How can I do this using CMake? The only thing i found was find_path, but as I am looking for another CMakeLists.txt file in whole project, that is in the specific folder I cannot effectively use it.

So what is the way to find path to folder of given name provided I know path to the root folder?

Comment: You can use `file(GLOB ...)` for search directory. But searching `CMakeLists.txt` file sounds weird... What is ultimate goal of that search?

Comment: @Tsyvarev so it's like There's a project, that is made of some subprojects and there can be dependencies between theese smaller projects, so if I want to compile some subproject that can be dependent to another one, then I need to build both of them, That's why I need something like this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the kind of dynamic subfolder location? Is this due to changing folder names e.g. including version numbers? If not - if you know the possible names in advance - I suggest that you CMake'ify all levels of subfolders. Meaning each subfolder should contain a CMakeLists.txt, even if it only contains a `add_subdirectory()` to include the next level. Therefore each subfolder level needs to know only about the next level. And if there are several possible next levels you could add e.g. an `if (EXISTS someSubFolder)` around your `add_subdirectory(someSubFolder)` call.

Comment: I forgot to mention that [if (EXISTS ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:if) needs the full path to work reliable. So it would be `if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/someSubFolder")`.

Comment: @DawidPi CMake will take care about which project depends on which and where a particular subproject should be built. CMake will discover if a project depends on another by examining it's inputs (source files, linked libraries). So you don't need to do it manually.

Comment: Well someSubFolder is a project with it's Cmake. Also someAnotherProject has it's own CmakeLists. When I want to compile just someSubFolder that is dependant to someAnotherFolder i want to do something like add_project(someAnotherProject). that's how I see it. I don;t want to hardcode sources and other stuff in all CMakeLists.

Comment: @tamas.kenez is right. @DawidPi You just add/include all subdirectories containing a project with a `CMakeLists.txt` and let CMake handle the dependencies. One trick I'm using for the "default"/"all" make rule: you will skip the compilation of projects that are not needed (are not named as a dependency in `add_dependencies()`), if you set [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_dir/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) with `set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1)` in your root `CMakeLists.txt` file and explicitly set it to `0` again for your executable target.